# Join 4 tables and collecting count from each table

Tags: mysql

I am trying count total column from each table with one common key. I can do with union statement. how i can use join

Query :

```
SELECT count(id) As WOWcount FROM `wow_track` where author_post_id='882' union SELECT count(*) As Followcount FROM `FolllowUserPost` where postID='882' union SELECT count(*) As CommentCount FROM `f9pix_comments` where post_id_fk ='882' union SELECT count(*)  As ViewCount FROM `viewPhotosTrack` where postID='882'
```

I have used following Query :

```
SELECT COUNT(a.author_post_id) AS WOWcount, COUNT(b.postID) AS Followcount, COUNT(c.post_id_fk) AS CommentCount, COUNT(d.postID) As ViewCount
FROM wow_track a
LEFT JOIN FolllowUserPost b ON a.author_post_id = b.postID
LEFT JOIN f9pix_comments c ON b.postID = c.post_id_fk
LEFT JOIN viewPhotosTrack d ON c.post_id_fk = d.postID
WHERE a.author_post_id='882'
```

But it displaying wrong count

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT COUNT(a.author_post_id) AS WOWcount, COUNT(b.postID) AS Followcount, COUNT(c.post_id_fk) AS CommentCount, COUNT(d.postID) As ViewCount
FROM wow_track a
LEFT JOIN FolllowUserPost b
ON a.author_post_id = b.postID
LEFT JOIN f9pix_comments c
ON b.postID = c.post_id_fk
LEFT JOIN viewPhotosTrack d
ON c.post_id_fk = d.postID
GROUP BY a.author_post_id
```

Comment: its fetch following error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS WOWcount, COUNT(b.*) AS Followcount, COUNT(c.*) AS CommentCount, COUNT(d.*' at line 1